# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta si los nombres de las columnas cambian cada año?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT IMPORTE_ENE_2021 * PORCENTAJE AS COMISION
FROM TBL_INGRESOS
```

Esta consulta esta dentro de un Stored Procedure, el detalle que para los siguientes años la tabla TBL_INGRESOS se elimina y se genera con un nuevo formato o sea que el próximo año el nombre de la columna Importe_Ene_2021 seria Importe_Ene_2022 y creo que lo ideal no es estar modificando el SP cada que cambie de año.

Existe alguna manera para poder obtener el nombre de las columnas y que se estén remplazando de manera automática en esta consulta ?

Comment: Pensaria que el proceso que tienen esta mal, ya que no deberia de pasar eso que dices todo se deberia de guardar en una tabla y podrian hacer una vista y unicamente por un parametro filtrar por año, pero si lo que quieres hacer es eso podrias obtener el nombre de la columna, pero tampoco dices si tu motor es SQL SERVER, MYSQL,ORACLE etc

Comment: Si, pero tengo limitantes para poder modificar el proceso desde 0, en el titulo de la pregunta especifico que es para SQL Server

Comment: Una disculpa es que no lo vi en el tag, entonces el sp si puedieras modificarlo no? para poder darte una respuesta mas concreta, podrias poner la estructura de esa tabla de igual modo por favor

Comment: Ntp, el SP literal solo es esa consulta bueno son todos los meses del año pero solo muestro enero ya que solucionando uno lo aplico para todos

Comment: Va te tratare de poner algo y con base a eso vemos si te funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente manejar los datos de esta forma va en contra del concepto de las bases relacionales, pero bueno, cosas más extrañas se han visto.  En primer lugar, debo decirte que tu problema no está tanto en como obtener el nombre de una columna, sino más bien como utilizarlo: cualquier consulta SQL estándar exige que conozcamos de antemano los nombres de las columnas que se usarán.

No hay muchas formas de resolver esto y me animaría a decir que tampoco sean lo mejor.

#### Estructura fija:

Si la tabla tuviera una estructura fija y lo mas permanente posible en el tiempo, podría sugerirte hacer una inserción tipo `INSERT Tabla SELECT * FROM TBL_INGRESOS`, es decir, supongamos por un momento que tienes una tabla como esta:

```
CREATE TBL_INGRESOS (
   OTRO_DATO        VARCHAR(255),
   IMPORTE_ENE_2021 NUMERIC(15,2),
   PORCENTAJE       NUMERIC(13,4)
)
```

Lo único que varía de año en año es el nombre de la columna `IMPORTE_ENE_<año>`, en este caso podrías definir una tabla temporal intermedia, para "renombrar" la columna por un nombre más genérico:

```
CREATE #TABLA_TEMPORAL (
   OTRO_DATO        VARCHAR(255),
   IMPORTE_ANIO     NUMERIC(15,2),
   PORCENTAJE       NUMERIC(13,4)
)

INSERT INTO TABLA_TEMPORAL
SELECT *
       FROM TBL_INGRESOS
```

Con esto hemos logrado renombrar la columna en cuestión por el nombre más genérico y útil `IMPORTE_ANIO` .La fragilidad de esto es clara, cuando se agregue una nueva columna o eventualmente se modifique el tipo de alguna de estas, la inserción fallará

Mediante esto, tu consulta final permanecerá estable:

```
SELECT IMPORTE_ANIO * PORCENTAJE AS COMISION
       FROM TBL_INGRESOS
```

---

#### Consulta dinámica:

Este tipo de consultas permiten mucha flexibilidad, pero la contra es que no suelen aprovechar las eventuales optimizaciones que podría hacer el motor, y en algunos casos, aunque no en este, pueden ser una entrada de inyeciones maliciosas de código.

```
DECLARE @AnioActual     INT;  
DECLARE @SQL            NVARCHAR(500);  

SET @AnioActual        = 2021

SET @SQL =  N'SELECT IMPORTE_ENE_' + CONVERT(@AnioActual) + ' * PORCENTAJE AS COMISION
FROM TBL_INGRESOS';
  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, 
                      @ParmDefinition = NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas SQL Server cuenta con unas tablas donde se pueden obtener los campos de las tablas, nos podemos apoyar de eso para buscar las columnas de las tablas, para mas información te dejo este enlace
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Ahora de acuerdo a lo que dices para un campo podrías hacer eso de lo que te comento y obtener la columna con un like de la que busques un ejemplo **IMPORTE_ENE_** y te traería la coincidencia y luego solo lo concatenas con lo siguiente yo te lo pongo en un **PRINT** pero ese PRINT se cambiaria por un **EXEC** para que ejecute la sentencia deseada quedando algo como esto

```
DECLARE @ColumnsConcact VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnsConcact=COLUMN_NAME +' * PORCENTAJE AS COMISION'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TBL_INGRESOS'--TBL_INGRESO
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'IMPORTE_ENE_%'


PRINT (
'SELECT '+@ColumnsConcact+' 
FROM TBL_INGRESOS' )
```

---Ahora como me comentas que seria de los meses se me ocurrió esto, solo los alias habría que ver como hacerlos ya que desconozco la funcionalidad, pero la idea de este es que concatena los campos por el importe y obtiene el valor de una vez.

```
DECLARE @ColumnsConcact VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnsConcact=COALESCE(@ColumnsConcact+',','')+COLUMN_NAME +' * PORCENTAJE AS COMISION'+COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TBL_INGRESOS'--TBL_INGRESOS

PRINT (
'SELECT '+@ColumnsConcact+' 
FROM TBL_INGRESOS' )
```

Cualquier duda que tengas házmela saber.

Saludos